# Is debugging complex HTML/CSS/JavaScript pages feasible?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Consider a complex [rich internet application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application) with lots of user interaction. I'm thinking of extensive drag-drop support, server-side user input validation, custom drawn UI controls such as an Outlook-like calendar, real-time UI feedback, etc... Would such an application be debuggable? I mean, can you easily step through the source code, place breakpoints, view the contents of variables, see the current call stack, use a profiler to pinpoint performance issues, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, why wouldn't it be?

Complexity just means more code to dig through, but tools like console.trace() from Firebug makes that easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be debug-able.

If you're using IE8 to test your site, you could use the Developer Tools to inspect individual HTML elements and change their CSS on the fly. There's also the ability to break into Javascript from the same interface.

If you're using Firefox, Firebug has almost identical abilities with a different interface.

Safari also has developer tools installed by default, you just have to go through the hoops of enabling them.

Answer (score 1):

When you are designing your application, design it with debugability and testability in mind. Make sure that individual parts are independently testable, you have enough test data, you have appropriate debug/probe points in your program logic, etc. Essentially if the complexity is properly managed, debugability won't be an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your job depended on it, you would find a way! :)

Seriously... a passenger jet has literally millions of parts and yet there are regular routine maintenance checks and if it breaks down it gets fixed. It's a very rare piece of software that approaches that much complexity.

Web app front ends tend to be relatively simple. Essentially you're just pushing some text from the server to the browser and making it pretty; and you're using various parts of the in-browser display as controls, some of which initiate some more text conversations with the server. There are lots of little things that can go wrong, of course, but much of the hardship is simply getting the browser (all of them!) to Do What You Mean.

The only truly difficult problems are those that are intermittent and/or timing sensitive. Those can be a bear to reproduce and trace. That calls for in-depth logical analysis of your source code and/or some specialized testing methods.